# Can I use Visual Studio 2010 with Microsoft Test Manager 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, microsoft-test-manager

At the moment I am using Visual Studio 2010 Premium and I want to buy Microsoft Test Manager. My question is: should I buy Test Manager 2010 or 2012? If so, what are the risks?

Will I have the supported platforms and configurations from [2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380742%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) or from [2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380742.aspx) considering both versions? (I am asking from the action recording point of view)

Thank you in advance and sorry if this seems like a stupid question but I am really confused

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Not all features in MTM 2012 is enabled, though.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj618301.aspx

Search down to "Connecting to TFS 2010".

You may already have found it, but this answer can be good for others asking the same question.